# Bootstrap model dialog closes on hitting the escape key

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and Angular to build the model dialog box , I do not want to close the model when the esc key pressed. Right now my model is closing when the escape key is hit.

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        Keyboard: false,
        templateUrl: 'userprofile.html',
        controller: 'UserProfileController'
    });


 <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;width:750px;height:500px">
                    <div class="userProfile">
                        <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                            <div class="row-flow">
                                <!-- First NAME -->
                                <div class="form-group-profile col-sm-6 required"
                                     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.firstName.$invalid && !userForm.firstName.$pristine }">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">FIRST NAME</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="firstName"
                                           required>

                                    <p ng-show="userForm.firstName.$invalid && !userForm.firstName.$pristine"
                                       class="help-block">First name is required</p>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Last NAME -->
                                <div class="form-group-profile col-sm-6 required"
                                     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.lastName.$invalid && !userForm.lastName.$pristine }">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">LAST NAME</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="lastName"
                                           required>

                                    <p ng-show="userForm.lastName.$invalid && !userForm.lastName.$pristine"
                                       class="help-block">Last name is required</p>
                                </div>
</div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your setup. you have `Keyboard` instead of `keyboard`.

Comment: using'keyboard' fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal').each(function () {
        $(this).modal({
            keyboard: false,
            show: false
        })
    });
});
```

I run the above code to disable the keyboard on all bootstrap modals. However I'm not using angular. keyboard property looks like its all lowercase. Try changing to all lowercase to see if it makes a difference?